# why I can't center those items with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I cannot center those items. I don't understand what i am doing wrong. I tried everything, but probably i am doing something that it's not right but i can't find out what!
------------------------------------------------------------------------[Content won't move!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF4bn.png)

```css
 
    
        .flexbox-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: row;
           
        }
        
        .flexbox-item {
            width: 200px;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #333;
            background-color: #dfdfdf;
        }
        
        .flexbox-item-1 {
            min-height: 200px;
        }
        
        .flexbox-item-2 {
            min-height: 200px;
        }
        
        .flexbox-item-3 {
            min-height: 200px;
        }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
     
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            
            <div class="flexbox-container">
                <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1"></div>
                <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2"></div>
                <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-3"></div>
            </div>
      
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You changed your code. Did the answers help or do you still have the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra closing `div` tag. Remove it and the code should work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You had a a closing element to the div with class "flexbox-container".

Try to wrap the flex items instead.

```css
       .flexbox-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: row;
           
        }
        
        .flexbox-item {
            width: 200px;
            margin: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #333;
            background-color: #dfdfdf;
        }
        
        .flexbox-item-1 {
            min-height: 200px;
        }
        
        .flexbox-item-2 {
            min-height: 200px;
        }
        
        .flexbox-item-3 {
            min-height: 200px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
     <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-1"></div>
     <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-2"></div>
     <div class="flexbox-item flexbox-item-3"></div>
</div>
```